# Instant read/write sync with iCal calendars avoiding the use of google calendars

Tags: sync, calendar

After using iphone/mac for a lot of time, I got a new android phone. I use on my macbook only ical calendars, and wonder what is the best app for syncing ical with my android phone. I have read something that you can sync first ical to google calendars and so on, but I Wonder if we can avoid this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sync with a calendar using the iCal format, there are apps available on the Playstore doing exactly that, like [iCalSync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/icalsync/jp.classmethod.us.android.icalsync) or [iCalSync2](http://www.appbrain.com/app/icalsync2/org.kc.and.ical), and there's also [The Missing Sync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/the-missing-sync-for-android/com.markspace.missingsync) (requiring a paid desktop component) or [SyncMate](http://www.appbrain.com/app/syncmate-for-android/com.eltima.android.syncmate) (specifically tailored for Mac, but again requiring a desktop component).

Most likely there are plenty of additional alternatives (take a look e.g. at [these search results](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=ical%20sync)). Unfortunately, I don't know of any native solution not involving 3<sup>rd</sup> party tools.